# How do I most elegantly express left join with aggregate SQL as LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

SQL:

```
SELECT
   u.id,
   u.name,
   isnull(MAX(h.dateCol), '1900-01-01') dateColWithDefault
FROM universe u
LEFT JOIN history h 
   ON u.id=h.id 
   AND h.dateCol<GETDATE()-1
GROUP BY u.Id, u.name
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution, albeit one that defers handling of the null value to the code, could be:

> DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);

```
var collection=
    from u in db.Universe
    select new
    {
        u.id,
        u.name,
        MaxDate =(DateTime?)
       (
           from h in db.History
           where u.Id == h.Id
           && h.dateCol < yesterday
           select h.dateCol 
       ).Max()
    };
```

This does not produce exactly the same SQL, but does provide the same logical result. Translating "complex" SQL queries to LINQ is not always straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
var collection=
    from u in db.Universe
    select new
    {
        u.id,
        u.name,
        MaxDate =(DateTime?)
       (
           from h in db.History
           where u.Id == h.Id
           && h.dateCol < yesterday
           select h.dateCol 
       ).Max()
    };
```

Just youse the above code and this should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer for you, but on the left join piece you can use the DefaultIfEmpty operator like so:

```
var collection = 
from u in db.Universe
join history in db.History on u.id = history.id into temp
from h in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where h.dateCol < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)
select u.id, u.name, h.dateCol ?? '1900-01-01'
```

I haven't had the need to do any `groupby` commands yet, so I left that out as to not send you down the wrong path.  Two other quick things to note.  I have been unable to actually join on two parameters although as above there are ways to get around it.  Also, the ?? operator works really well in place of the `isnull` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the `join into` construct to create a group query.

```
TestContext db = new TestContext(CreateSparqlTripleStore());
var q = from a in db.Album
        join t in db.Track on a.Name equals t.AlbumName into tracks
        select new Album{Name = a.Name, Tracks = tracks};
foreach(var album in q){
    Console.WriteLine(album.Name);
    foreach (Track track in album.Tracks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(track.Title);
    }
}
```